# Is "ж" palato-alveolar or retroflex?

Tags: произношение

As a native Portuguese speaker, I was told "ж" in Russian is pronounced like the Portuguese and French "j" (IPA: ʒ), a [voiced palato-alveolar fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palato-alveolar_fricative).

However according to Wikipedia the Russian "ж" is a [retroflex fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_fricative) (IPA: ʐ). Is this the only correct pronunciation, and if so, how incorrect is the approximation above?

Comment: This is an incredibly lovely way to characterize pronunciation of Russian "ж" as "voiced palato-alveolar fricative". I don't argue linguistic (or anatomic for that matter) correctness of that definition but it is as if to call "бульон с яйцом" as "консоме с пашотом". :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wikipedia is right, Russian `Ж` is a retroflex fricative (IPA: ʐ), and the sound sample they have in the article is exactly how it sounds in Russian.

If you pronounce it like the Portuguese and French "j" (IPA: ʒ), you will be understood well, but this will add a foreign accent to your speech, I'd advise sticking to the correct, retroflex fricative variant. Russian `Ж` (IPA: ʐ) can never be "soft" (palatalized), even when in spelling it is followed by the palatalizing vowels (е, ё, и, ю, я,), so `жизнь` is actually pronounced as `*жызнь`, `Жюль Верн` as `*Жуль Верн`, etc.

In Russian there is another phoneme, a long (gemminated) voiced palato-alveolar fricative (IPA: ʑː which can also be transcribed as ʒ:), which is normally spelled `ЖЖ`, like in `вожжи, дрожжи, жжение, жужжать, можжевельник`. But this sound is now substituted in the speech of most people by /ʐ:/, that is it loses its palatal nature, the tendency in Russian is to have all Ж-like phonemes non-palatalized.

Comment: ЖЖ, like in вожжи, дрожжи sounds is soft, completely different from hard ЖЖ, like in жжение, жужжать, можжевельник

Comment: @A-K - Any proof? I think it's just your individual pronunciation, not the standard. Here's a Russian pronunciation dictionary with the transcription that proves that both variants are possible, the soft and hard ЖЖ: [жжение](http://dazor.narod.ru//books/slovari/polistat/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0146.htm), [жужжать](http://dazor.narod.ru//books/slovari/polistat/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0148.htm), [можжевельник](http://dazor.narod.ru//books/slovari/polistat/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0263.htm).

Comment: The pronouncing of palatalised (soft) and long [ж'] is a remarkable part of the Moscow's and some other dialects. In the official language it is just long [ж] in words which are written with double ж letter and [жд'] in words with group жд before a palatalising vowel letter.

Comment: But returning to the question that was asked Yellow Sky is right: [ʒ] will be understood but will sound a bit foreign whereas the most correct description is [ʐ].